# Append Struct object into LinkedList - C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I’m trying to append a struct object to a linked list. The data is read from stdin. The int attribute gets appended correctly, but all char * values previously appended keep getting replaced by the new input.

My append and getElement functions work properly for string inputs.

Here is my code:

```
#include "List.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct EventObj{
    char *name;
    int time;
} EventObj;
typedef EventObj* EventPtr;

void add(ListPtr a, EventObj *event);
void printTime(ListPtr a);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ListPtr a1 = newList(0, NULL, NULL);
    
  char func[10], agenda[256], eventName[256], buffer[256];
  int time;

  printf("%s\n", "Begin reading inputs and appending events");
  while(fgets(buffer, 256, stdin) != NULL){
    sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s %d", func, agenda, eventName, &time);
    EventPtr event = malloc(sizeof(*event));
    event->time = time;
    event->name = eventName;

    printf("%d ", event->time);
    printf("%s\n", event->name);
    appendList(a1, event);
  }

  printf("%s\n", "Print from the list after appending");
  printTime(a1);
  }
  


void printTime(ListPtr a){
  for (int i=0; i <length(a); i++){
    EventPtr cur = getElement(a, i);
    printf("%d ", cur->time);
    printf("%s\n", cur->name);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Begin reading inputs and appending events
9 event1
10 event2
12 event3
8 event4
Print from the list after appending
9 event4
10 event4
12 event4
8 event4
// this should be event1 event2 event3 event4
```

Append function:

```
bool appendList( ListPtr L, void *data ){
  if(L == NULL){
    printf("%s", "appendList: NULL List");
    return false;
  }
    NodePtr node = newNode(data);
    if(node == NULL){
    printf("%s", "appendList: NULL Node");
    return false;
  }
  node-> next = L -> head;
  L -> head = node;
  L ->length ++;
  return true;
}
```

getElement:

```
void *getElement( ListPtr L, int i){
  if(L == NULL || i > L->length){
    printf("%s", "delElement: No entry or List found\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  NodePtr tmp = L-> head;
  i = L->length - i - 1;
  while(tmp != NULL && i > 0){
    tmp = tmp -> next;
    i --;
  }
  return tmp -> data;
}
```

Comment: error messages belong on stderr: `fprintf(stderr, "%s", "delElement: No entry or List found\n");`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this statement

```
event->name = eventName;
```

in the while loop

```
while(fgets(buffer, 256, stdin) != NULL){
```

the pointer `name` points to the same array `eventName`. So the last string that was stored in the array `eventName` is shown for all nodes because all nodes point to this array.

You need dynamically to allocate memory for a character array in each node and copy the string stored in the array `eventName` in this dynamically allocated array.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked!!! I do char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(eventName)), then strcpy(tmp, eventName) and  finally event->name = tmp.